# Set user role at signing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made a table of user abilities with 3 types: admin, bidder, seacher.

```
user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
   can :read, :all
    can :manage, Job do |job|
    job.try(:user) == user
  end
  if user.admin?
     can :manage, :all
   elsif
    user.has_role? :bidder
    can :manage, Job, :user => {user_id: user.id}
    elsif 
    user.has_role? :searcher
    can :read, :all

   end
```

And at my pages_controller I made this

```
def home
    if current_user
      redirect_to jobs_path
    end

      @searcher_plan = Plan.find(1)
      @bidder_plan = Plan.find(2)
  end
```

How can I make it to associate to the role during the signin?, I tryed this but it doesn't work

```
<%= link_to "Bidder Account", new_user_registration_path(plan: @bidder_plan.id) %>
```

Comment: What is the association between user and plan?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you want but, according to your question title you can create own callback:

```
# app/controllers/your_sessions_controller.rb
class YourSessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  after_login :set_role, only: :create

  def set_role
    # do here what you need
  end
end
```